# Enable Chrome extension for certain urls?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first Chrome extension and was wondering if there's a way for it only to be enabled/displayed on the toolbar when visiting Google Drive?

Reading through the dev guide it looks like I need to either set permissions or content_scripts=>matches in my manifest.json file to something like this:

```
"permissions" : {"https://drive.google.com/", "http://drive.google.com/"}
```

or this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://drive.google.com/", "http://drive.google.com/"],
     ...
  }
```

Neither seem to be working as my extension shows up on every page I visit. Is there another resource I can take a look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"displayed on the toolbar" sounds like you're talking about a page or browser action.  Since you only want some pages, this means you want a [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction).  If you then want to interact with the DOM, then you’ll need a content script.  And you’ll want `"matches": ["*://drive.google.com/*"]`.  The first `*` equals the two hosts you listed; the second `*` means "any url with that prefix" and may have been your original problem.  See [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for more details.

If you don’t need a content script, you have the option to use [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) in your event script to show the page action.  And `"permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent"]`.

Comment: Yep. I read through the guide and decided I needed a page action. That did the trick. Thanks for the response!

Comment: would be perfect if you'd share the whole code

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this using the `v3` manifest.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.action.disable();

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    const rules = {
      conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: { hostSuffix: ".example.com", schemes: ["https"] },
        }),
      ],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()],
    };

    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rules]);
  });
});

[Example][1] in the chrome docs


  [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#emulating-pageactions-with-declarativecontent
```